# Not able to generate JSON file using JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have 7MB of .json file and I am filtering the data with my node.js and storing the data into a `displayMe` array. When I display that shorted array in console it's visible in that. But when I try to write that array using `JSON.stringify`. I get a json file with blank array.

Here is the code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var data = fs.readFileSync('India2011.json');

var myData=JSON.parse(data);//contains main array

var len=myData.length;//main array length

var k=1;
var count=0;

var displayMe=[];
var canRead=0;
var cannotRead=0;
for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {

    for (var j = k; j <=35; j++) {
        var obj={};

    if ((myData[i]["State Code"]==(j))&&(myData[i]["Total/ Rural/ Urban"]=="Total")&&(myData[i]["Age-group"]=="All ages")) {

        obj["Literate - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Literate - Persons"]);
        obj["Illiterate - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Illiterate - Persons"]);
        obj["Total - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Total Persons"]);
        //sort.push(obj);
        displayMe[myData[i]["Area Name"]]=(obj);
        count+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Total Persons"]));
        canRead+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Literate - Persons"]));
        cannotRead+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Illiterate - Persons"]));
        ++k;
        };
    };
};

fs.writeFile( "displayMe.json", JSON.stringify( displayMe ), "utf8");// this part not working.

console.log(displayMe);//this is working
```

This is the console output:

```
[ 'State - JAMMU & KASHMIR': { 'Literate - Persons': 7067233,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 5474069,
    'Total - Persons': 12541302 },
  'State - HIMACHAL PRADESH': { 'Literate - Persons': 5039736,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 1824866,
    'Total - Persons': 6864602 },
  'State - PUNJAB': { 'Literate - Persons': 18707137,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 9036201,
    'Total - Persons': 27743338 },
  'State - CHANDIGARH': { 'Literate - Persons': 805438,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 250012,
    'Total - Persons': 1055450 },
  'State - UTTARAKHAND': { 'Literate - Persons': 6880953,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 3205339,
    'Total - Persons': 10086292 },
  'State - HARYANA': { 'Literate - Persons': 16598988,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 8752474,
    'Total - Persons': 25351462 },
  'State - NCT OF DELHI': { 'Literate - Persons': 12737767,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 4050174,
    'Total - Persons': 16787941 },
  'State - RAJASTHAN': { 'Literate - Persons': 38275282,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 30273155,
    'Total - Persons': 68548437 },
  'State - UTTAR PRADESH': { 'Literate - Persons': 114397555,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 85414786,
    'Total - Persons': 199812341 },
  'State - BIHAR': { 'Literate - Persons': 52504553,
    'Illiterate - Persons': 51594899,
    'Total - Persons': 104099452 }
    ]
```

Comment: Any errors you see in console? Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile

Comment: Btw, your JSON is invalid. You can't have single quotes, nor have objects key/values as items in an array (they must be in an object).

Comment: Yep - incorrect JSON, try an online JSON validator. http://jsonlint.com

Comment: `[ "key": { value: 0 } ]` is invalid. Try something like: `[ { "key": { value: 0 } } ]` instead.

Comment: no error on console. Also I am getting a displayMe.json file with an array with no elements. like this : []

Comment: @evolutionxbox More like `[ { "key": { "value" : 0 } } ]`

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are right I fixed the problem. That output was invalid json. shall I share the correct code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the above js code was not generating array in proper JSON format. I tried and fixed that. here is working code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var data = fs.readFileSync('India2011.json');

var myData=JSON.parse(data);//contains main array

var len=myData.length;//main array length

var k=1;
var count=0;

var displayMe=[];
var canRead=0;
var cannotRead=0;
for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
     var obj2={};//changes here
    for (var j = k; j <=35; j++) {
        var obj={};
        var header;//changes here

    if ((myData[i]["State Code"]==(j))&&(myData[i]["Total/ Rural/ Urban"]=="Total")&&(myData[i]["Age-group"]=="All ages")) {

        obj["Literate - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Literate - Persons"]);
        obj["Illiterate - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Illiterate - Persons"]);
        obj["Total - Persons"]=parseInt(myData[i]["Total Persons"]);

        header= myData[i]["Area Name"];//changes here
        obj2[header]=obj;//changes here

        displayMe.push(obj2);//changes here
        count+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Total Persons"]));
        canRead+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Literate - Persons"]));
        cannotRead+=(parseInt(myData[i]["Illiterate - Persons"]));
        ++k;
        //console.log("Addesd "+myData[i]["Total Persons"]+" Time j: "+k+" State name"+myData[i]["Area Name"]+" i:"+i+"k:"+k+" count "+count);
        };
    };
};

fs.writeFile( "displayMe.json", JSON.stringify( displayMe ), "utf8");

console.log(displayMe);
```

that was the few changes. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this line:

```
var displayMe = [];
```

You're initializing `displayMe` to be an empty array. However, you are subsequently treating that array as an object:

```
displayMe[myData[i]["Area Name"]] = (obj);
```

This won't stringify to JSON properly, because arrays are supposed to have particular properties (like `length`) that `JSON.stringify()` depends on.

Instead, initialize `displayMe` to be an empty object:

```
var displayMe = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "But when I try to write that array using JSON.stringify. I get a json file with blank array."

That's because JSON doesn't seem to *parse* or *stringify* named properties of an *Array hybrid*.

Your array length is 0. And the result will most certainly be = [].

You will have to replace Array:

```
[ 'State - JAMMU [...] Persons': 104099452 }  ]
```

with a proper Object:

```
{ 'State - JAMMU [...] Persons': 104099452 }  }
```